# How to join after groupby in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following sample sql
This sql didn't work.

I'd like to join after group by. I tried to extract table as `tran` then I hope to join description table`t2` to `tran`.

```
select *
from (  
    select count(t.code),t.code
    from  table t
    group by t.code
    order by count(t.code) desc ) as tran

left join code_description t2
on tran.code = t2.code
```

I suffered following error

`ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`

What is a wrong point ? how can I fix them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this please:

```
select *
from (  
    select count(t.code) as kol,t.code
    from  table t
    group by t.code
     ) as tran

left join code_description t2
on tran.code = t2.code
order by tran.kol desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `order by` out of subquery

```
select 
  *
from 
  (  
    select 
      count(t.code) as total,
      t.code
    from  table t
    group by t.code
  ) as tran

left join code_description t2
on tran.code = t2.code
order by tran.total desc
```